# Why am I getting a "call to undefined method" error when trying to display a form in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi i have written the below code in my cakephp.

```
<?php
    //Posts is the name of my View folder, add, edit arethe pages in Posts folder.
echo $this->Posts('add_or_edit');
?>
<fieldset>
<legend>
<?php  _('Add a Post'); ?>
</legend>
Please fill in all the fields.
<?php
echo $form->create('Post');
echo $form->error('Post.title');
echo $form->input('Post.title',array('id'=>'posttitle','label'=>'title','size'=>'50','maxlength'=>'255','error'=>false));
echo $form->error('Post.content');
echo $form->input('Post.content',array('id'=>'postcontent','type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Content:','rows'=>'10','error'=>false));
echo $form->end(array('label'=>'Submit Post'));
?>
</fieldset>
```

Well whenever i try to display the above code i am getting an error like this

```
 Call to undefined method View::Posts() in C:\wamp\www\cake_php\app\View\Posts\add.ctp on line 2
```

Is there something wrong with my code or do i need to change my View files ?

Comment: What do you expect echo $this->Posts('add_or_edit'); to do? This is your problem, $this refers to the view - it has no idea about controllers or models.

Comment: I just use it to identify whether its the edit file or add file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this works for you...
You had missed $this

```
        <fieldset>
        <legend>
        <h2> Add a Post Here </h2>
        </legend>
        Please fill in all the fields.
        <?php
        echo $this->form->create('Post');
        echo $this->form->error('Post.title');
        echo $this->form->input('Post.title',array('id'=>'posttitle','label'=>'title','size'=>'50','maxlength'=>'255','error'=>false));
        echo $this->form->error('Post.content');
        echo $this->form->input('Post.content',array('id'=>'postcontent','type'=>'textarea','label'=>'Content:','rows'=>'10','error'=>false));
        echo $this->form->end(array('label'=>'Submit Post'));
        ?>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Yup i realised that i missed $this nw only.....worked for me perfectly fine..........Thanks